# apache httpclient + ntlm Authentication

Tags: java, file-upload, ntlm, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a client to upload a file to a server over https post. It uses proxy and this is my code

```
public void upload() throws Exception {

    //create default client
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    //set proxy authentication if specified
    if (proxy.equals("yes") && proxyAuth.equals("yes")){
    client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(address, port),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword));
    }

    //set proxy if specified
    if (proxy.equals("yes")){
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(address, port);
        client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);
    }

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    File dir = new File(inputFilePath);
    File[] fileArray = dir.listFiles(); 
    File file = fileArray[0];

    FileBody uploadFilePart = new FileBody(file);

    entity.addPart("file", uploadFilePart);
    entity.addPart("username", new StringBody(username));
    entity.addPart("password", new StringBody(password));

    post.setEntity(entity);

    //execute post and get response
    String response = EntityUtils.toString(client.execute(post).getEntity(), "UTF-8");

    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    log4j.info(response);

    if(!response.substring(0, 3).equalsIgnoreCase("200")){
        Exception e = new Exception("An error has occurred server side: ");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is this works perfectly sometimes and sometimes i get the below error.

> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractAuthenticationHandler.selectScheme(AbstractAuthenticationHandler.java:149) - Authentication scheme ntlm not supported"

Comment: Have you tried to follow the http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html instructions?

Comment: ya tried that. but still same issue

Comment: if you are using httpclient 3 you can use this tool to simplify such authentication scenarious https://github.com/DovAmir/httpclientAuthHelper

Answer (score 4):

You need to register the NTLM handler as explained in http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html:

```
client.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());
```

Comment: The link you posted here is for using the Samba NTLM implementation. You should be able (these days) to use Apache's own implementation (4.7): https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to -
Instead of this: 
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword)

use this:
   new NTCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword, "localhostname", "domain")